# How to apply the Bootstrap template to the MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am changing the style of my MVC project, for that I resorted to [Bootswach](http://bootswatch.com) and its different templates, the problem is that the visual changes in the views are not effective, for example ...

It has a very extensive form vertically, as follows

[image: Form]

and you want to align objects to the right and to the left in the following way

[image: Form expected]

to make this change use the tag `<div class = "col-md-6">`
but I'm not getting the expected result, why does this happen?

now I will tell you how to implement this template ....

1.- download the bootstrap watch bootstrap.css file and add it to my project

[image: Bootstrapwatch]

2.- in my BundleConfig.cs change the boostrap.css file that you download

[image: BundleConfig]

3.- And modify my view finally

My View:

```
<h2>Crear Producto</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Productoes", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.v_Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.v_Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.v_Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FotoFile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="file-input-new">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:280px">
                            <div tabindex="500" class="form-control file-caption">
                                <div class="file-caption-name" id="NombreArchivo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-btn" style="height:auto">
                                <div tabindex="500" class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                                    Buscar Foto...
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelo => modelo.FotoFile, new { type = "file", id = "files" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Precio_Minimo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Precio_Minimo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Precio_Minimo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Precio_Maximo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Precio_Maximo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Precio_Maximo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Activo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Activo)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Activo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stock, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Stock, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Stock, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.f_Compra, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.f_Compra, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.f_Compra, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comentarios, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comentarios, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comentarios, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoCategoria, "Categoria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Kn_CodigoCategoria", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoCategoria, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-outline-success" />
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>

    </div>

}
```

with these two steps I can already visualize the changes of the template, but I said previously I can not move my objects as far as I want,
what am I doing wrong? Do I have to add other references to my BundleConfig? do I have to install something in the project?

any help for me?

Comment: So you already have Bootstrap taking effect? It sounds like you may have CSS issues that conflict with the margin / padding then. In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: where is your html? Did it work with bootstrap only?

Comment: I have modified my question as you wish @ObsidianAge

Comment: I have modified my question as you wish @CodingYoshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `col-x-y` divs inside a div with class `.row` and inside a container or it will not work. Similar to this (you do not need the `col` class but I just put it here so it is easier to see the columns in the fiddle):

```
<div class="container">
  <!--This will not work -->
  <div class="col col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="col col-sm-6">.col-sm-6</div>
  <div class="col col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
  <!-- This will work -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-6">.col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CodingYoshi/x5or6aeo/1/) so you can see this yourself.